# When using Google Search Console change of address should I also submit the new site to the search index?

Tags: google-search-console, google-index

I have successfully submitted a change of address from old domain to new domain today.

I'm wondering should I ALSO use "Fetch as Google" and  submit the pages to be indexed or will that confuse Google? Does the change of address already take care of the submit to index process?

Comment: What else have you done? For example, have you redirected the old site to the new site??

Comment: To have submitted the change of address, the site must already be redirecting.   Google requires it to be so to submit the change of address.

Answer (score 1):

If you have submitted the change of address, there is no need to submit the new site for inclusion in the search index.   The change of address will let Google know that you want the new site indexed but not the old site.    It will take Google several days to make the change and have your new site in the search index.

Fetching the new site and submitting it to be indexed shouldn't hurt or confuse Google.   It just isn't necessary.